# Теоретический вопрос по Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

В Ajax'e есть функция .load('something.html'). А есть ли функция, которая делает обратное ? Которая выгружает что-либо из страницы ?

Comment: Не менее теоретический ответ - есть. Ибо для этого он и задуман. С выгрузки и начинает весь этот ajax.

Comment: что значит _выгружает_?

Comment: Я бы ещё уточнил что подразумевается под Ajax

Comment: @Grundy  ну если .load() загружает содержимое другого документа, то как от этого содержимого избавится потом ?

Comment: @Sergey ну и каким образом можно избавится от того, что я загрузил с другого файла ?

Comment: .remove() попробуйте )

Comment: Если вы загрузили свое "содержимое" в  DOM, то просто удалите его оттуда с помощью jquery функции empty(). Если оно у Вас  в JS хариниться то просто занулите переменную.

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления дочерних элементов в jQuery есть функция [empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)